# android google apis turn off google map

Tags: android, google-maps

We're building an application where the user has the ability to overlay lots of geospatial data on top of a map. The google apis have terrific support for this; allowing vector features to be drawn as well as a tileoverlay class.

The downside is that their map is ALWAYS the basemap. The only way this is a downside is if a user says "i dont want that" or something. I don't think that's likely, but it's possible. I'm curious if there's a way to turn the google tiles portion off, or tell it to hide it's google tiles, and tell it to stop trying to get tiles from google? I want to use the api, but be able to not show the google map, do-able?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the map type to MAP_TYPE_NONE?

Comment: wow. yep that did it. that did not come up at all when i originally asked this question, maybe the APIs were too new.